# Pass an array from .jsp file to .js file

Tags: javascript, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to transfer java array to javaScript array using jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516565/how-to-transfer-java-array-to-javascript-array-using-jsp)

After googling I am still not able to pass array from .jsp file to js file.
Can somebody help me out?

In my .jsp file i have an array and I wan to call a function in .js file which accepts this array. How to call this function?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516565/how-to-transfer-java-array-to-javascript-array-using-jsp

Comment: I didn't get anything useful from here. Can somebody post some code for this?

Answer (score 0):

By passing an array from .jsp to js file I guess you mean your Javascript script needs to "call" a script return by a JSP file. And that script contains a function that returns an array? 
If so have you looked at returning JSON from your JSP?

Answer (score 0):

For simple arrays, you can convert the array to a comma-delimited string using an implode function, pass the string to javascript, and then use `split(str)` in Javascript to get an array back. More complicated arrays may cause issues with this.