# Servlet array to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have to generate a bidimensional array for my `extjs` application.

I have the `mysql` interrogation from the servlet but I need to save these values to a bidimensional array in javascript.

The thing that I have thought to work about is saving the bidimensional array from the servlet (using tomcat) in a bidimensional array in my `jsp` page, where I use the script for the `extjs`.

My problem is understanding how can recall from servlet to `jsp` page the variable which I need and save her value in a javascript variable.
Example:

**Servlet**

```
package connect;

import java.awt.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
import jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.JSONFunctions;

@WebServlet("/learn")
public class iServlet_debug_1 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public iServlet_debug_1() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?user=root&password=pass";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        Statement stm = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = ((java.sql.Statement) stm).executeQuery("select * from romanzi");

        //ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> storeArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
        //String[][] storeArray;
        String storeArray = null;
        //int n = 0;
        //int m = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            //first method
            /*ArrayList<Object> arr =  new ArrayList<Object>();
            ArrayList<Object> arr =  new ArrayList<Object>();
            arr.add(rs.getInt("id"));
            arr.add(rs.getString("titolo"));
            arr.add(rs.getString("ISBN"));
            arr.add(rs.getString("genere"));
            arr.add(rs.getInt("Npagine"));
            arr.add(rs.getInt("editore"));
            storeArray.add(arr);*/

            //second method
            /*storeArray[n][m]= rs.getString("id");
            m++;
            storeArray[n][m]= rs.getString("titolo");
            m++;
            storeArray[n][m]= rs.getString("ISBN");
            m++;
            storeArray[n][m]= rs.getString("genere");
            m++;
            storeArray[n][m]= rs.getString("Npagine");
            m++;
            storeArray[n][m]= rs.getString("editore");
            m=0;
            n++;*/
            storeArray += "["+rs.getString("id")
                        +","+rs.getString("titolo")
                        +","+rs.getString("ISBN")
                        +","+rs.getString("genere")
                        +","+rs.getString("Npagine")
                        +","+rs.getString("editore")
                        +"]";
            if(rs.next())
            {
                storeArray+= ",";
                rs.previous();
            }

        }
        response.setContentType("text/plain"); // sets the content type
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // sets the encoding
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.append(storeArray); // writes the value of the String to the response
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        PrintWriter err = response.getWriter();
        err.print("<html><head></head><body>" + e.getMessage() + "</body></html>");
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
  }

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);

}

  }
```

**Javascript**

```
var temp = (storeArray Servlet variable);
var finalArray = JSON.parse("[" + temp + "]");

or

var finalArray = eval("[" + temp + "]");
```

The result that i need is something like this:

```
var finalArray = [
      ['value10','value11','value12'],
      ['value20','value21','value22'],
      ['value30','value31','value32']
];
```

For next implementation I need to understand how can i retrieve the servlet value and convert it in javascript variable onload of the jsp page.

Substantially:

- I have to pass: an array of arrays variable from servlet to javascript (because i need the method that allows me to do the communication from servlet variable and javascript variable)
- Or a String from servlet to javascript variable and after split in an array of arrays

That's all.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my "not really good" english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transfer java array to javaScript array using jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516565/how-to-transfer-java-array-to-javascript-array-using-jsp)

Comment: Not exactly ... There is only one for saving the elements dimensional java in an equally javascript. My array is two-dimensional and all the data transfer part between servlet and javascript is missing .... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem with GSON/JSON libraries.
Bottom the code:

**Servlet**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?user=root&password=pass";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        Statement stm = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = ((java.sql.Statement) stm).executeQuery("select * from novels");

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> storeArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
        ArrayList<Object> arr =  new ArrayList<Object>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            arr.add(rs.getInt("id"));
            arr.add(rs.getString("title"));
            arr.add(rs.getString("ISBN"));
            arr.add(rs.getString("genre"));
            arr.add(rs.getInt("Npages"));
            arr.add(rs.getString("publisher"));
            storeArray.add(arr);
            arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonStore = gson.toJson(storeArray);
        response.setContentType("text/plain"); // sets the content type
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // sets the encoding
        request.setAttribute("array", jsonStore);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        PrintWriter err = response.getWriter();
        err.print("<html><head></head><body>" + e.getMessage() + "</body></html>");
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // error management
        }
    }
}
```

With

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStore = gson.toJson(storeArray);
```

is possible translate the storeArray in a JSON string for javascript;

With this

```
response.setContentType("text/plain"); // sets the content type
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // sets the encoding
request.setAttribute("array", jsonStore);
```

we can send the JSON string to front end part;

The JSON string variable can we retrived from jsp with the part below:

```
<%
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/generate");
    rd.include(request, response);
    String store = (String)request.getAttribute("array");
%>
```

And finally we can store the variable to a javascript variable with this:

```
var temp = <%=store%>;
```

that read the variable as a javascript "ArrayList" variable!

I hope you will find it useful.